# HTML: How to send an email via an html link?

Tags: html, blogs

I learned to write html and css code a month ago. I am in the process of making a blog website for my friend. I got there when I made the about page. And I made a button there that would have made it possible to talk to my friend via email. And it didn't work :(
(I can't code in PHP)

I tried this:
`<a href="mailto:friend@gmail.com" target="_self"> <button type="button">Let's Talk!</button> </a>`
I thought it would open a page with only the email and nothing else. (of course the recipient and the subject)

Comment: `<a>` elements are not allowed to contain `<button>` elements.

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:html-email]. Is this code in an HTML or is it code on a weblike like the second sentence of your question says?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:gmail] which says *ONLY use this tag for PROGRAMMING questions related to **Gmail's APIs***. That doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: Ok! But then how can I do it?

Comment: Unless you are using a browser which chokes on the invalid HTML I pointed out in my initial comment: Like that. (Hence why I voted to close the question as "Cannot reproduce").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML you wrote should work, even if it's not strictly valid. To be clear:

You cannot send an email directly via HTML, it is up to the web browser itself how a `href="mailto:"` link is handled.

For example, Firefox will attempt to start the default email client of the operating system when a `mailto:` link is clicked. You can also configure what [Firefox should do with mailto: links](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-program-used-open-email-links). There are similar configurations for other browsers and operating systems.

Websites and apps can also ask the browser or operating system for permission to become the default email client.

In short, control of `mailto:` links is up to the browser, and not something you can control from HTML.

Comment: Also note that `<button>` in the post should be removed to make the HTML valid.